# Limit of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone explain why this limit is = 1/3.

[image]

Comment: because $2n^3+3n^2+n$ is equivalent at $n=+\infty$ to $2n^3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

multiplying by $$\frac{1}{n^3}$$ gives us $$\frac{2+\frac{3}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}{6}$$

Comment: Ah, I should have been multiplying. =)

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{1}{n^3}\dfrac{2n^3+3n^2+n}{6}=\lim_{n \to \infty}\dfrac{2+3/n+1/n^2}{6}=\dfrac{2}{6}=\dfrac{1}{3}$$

Explanation : Since $1/n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty$ the last two terms on the numerator will approach $0$. What remains is the first term.

Answer (score 0):

Here is small hint for your faster calculation. Whenever limit tends to infinity, take highest power common and cancel it , and limit will be coefficient of highest power divided by coefficient of lowest power.

$$\lim_{x \to\infty} \dfrac{a_1x^n + a_2x^{n-1} + a_3 x^{n-2} \cdots a_n x^1}{b_1x^n + b_2x^{n-1} + b_3 x^{n-2} \cdots b_n x^1}=\dfrac{a_1}{b_1}$$

In you limit it is $\frac 26$